# UIBarButtonItem set Action touch up inside by programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

in my project , i kept a UIBarbuttonItem by programming  and it is working fine but my problem is. if i click on that it is not  blinking like normal UIButton Touch up inside event like.
below how i implemented.

```
UIBarButtonItem *todayButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today"
         style:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
        target:self action:@selector(showTodaysDate)];
[toolBarItemArr addObject:todayButton];
[todayButton release];
```

how to implement touchup event programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the *UIBarButtonItem* to **glow**, when you touch on it. Actually it is a behavior of *UIButton*, not *UIBarButtonItem*. *UIButton* has a property **showsTouchWhenHighlighted** which makes the button to glow on touch, if set *YES*. There is no way to make a *UIBarButtonItem* to behave like this.

Answer (score 2):

UIBarButtonItem Doesn't have any touchupInside event. It can not behave like a UIButton. It also doesn't have selected or disable image. It only have enable or disable state. So you can't replicate it like UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Style into   UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered and You don't want to implement any event for the Barbutton Items. Basically Bar button Items works for touch up inside event.